# How do you back up an android app?

Tags: java, android, backup, reinstall

I just had my app crash and now after alot of work its back to were I had it, I was wondering how would I back up the app so I can reInstall is again if this ever happens again?

Comment: what do you mean by app crash and you have to work on it to get it back to same state ?????

Comment: I have been programing an app but I messed it up so how and it was past the point of repairable so I had to start again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

u should use a version control system, example: git version control

http://git-scm.com/

happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

use a version control system.. like svn or git ... in any case even if you were not using this, you should have taken backup of your code regularly... these version control system manages this for you easily...

Answer (score 0):

This question is not specific to Java or Android, but rather, how to "backup" code properly. As others have already mentioned, you should be using source control systems such as [Git](http://git-scm.com) or [Subversion](http://subversion.apache.org). Not only will this "backup" your code, it will allow you to track the changes you make to the code as well as maintain multiple versions of your code.